# Is it possible measure the relative distance and bearing among robots?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My name is Andrew and I am new of this community. I would like to know if it exists an off-the-shelf hardware that allows to measure relative distances and bearing among robots. As far as I know ultrasonic sensors are used to meaure relative distances, but it is not possible understand who is my neighbor, they tell me just there is someone over there!

Thank you,
Andrew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103541/is-it-possible-measure-the-relative-distance-and-bearing-among-robots?/) by [-Andrew-](https://answers.ros.org/users/9051/-andrew-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many sensors which can be used for this purpose, but it will require integration. The most common way to do this is to use a camera and visual markers such as AR Tags. See http://wiki.ros.org/ar_tools for more info.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2